# How to get offsetWidth and offsetHeight values after add css class to change them

Tags: css, angular

I have a Component which update css class

```css
.slider-horizontal {
  width: 210px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```
    import {Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
    export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('picker') picker: ElementRef;

      constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) {

      }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.picker.nativeElement, 'slider-horizontal', true);

        console.log(this.picker.nativeElement.offsetWidth);//old value 
        console.log(this.picker.nativeElement.offsetHeight);//old value
      }
    }
```

How do I get the new values which are changed after apply css?

Comment: Please provide a plunker demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made a plnkr with a working example you can find it here: [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/aAoDCGmeEBaU7jM8Z0ep/), however the results seem to be as expected:

```
679
0

210
20
```

So in my plunk it appears to be working...

Although I'm pretty sure the change detection is not running in your case you should try to invoke it manually.

Add this to your constructor

```
private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
```

So your constructor would look like this

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer,
            private el: ElementRef,
            private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

}
```

And call the change detection like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderer.setElementClass(this.picker.nativeElement, 'slider-horizontal', true);

  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

  console.log(this.picker.nativeElement.offsetWidth);//old value 
  console.log(this.picker.nativeElement.offsetHeight);//old value
}
```

Now the values you'll see in the console should be fine.

Comment: I think the `detectChanges` is reduntant here. Would be great if @loi mai provide a real example

Comment: @yurzui i remember having issues with this before and manually invoking the change detection solved it (RC builds though) but indeed a code example would be really useful

Comment: Thank you for your plnkr. That is exactly how my code look like. But I use angular-cli. Sometimes it í working correctly, but sometimes it is not. Also its width follows dynamically to web browsers window width when I do debug, I mean I changed the size of browser window while debugging. I add `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` but no different.